# VBA - assign TextBox value to varaible error

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, textbox

I am writing a VBA code using a useform, which includes 3 ComboBoxes and 3 TextBoxes.

Whenever a user chooses any value from the list provided by the Comboboxes, the code works. The problems start when I try to combine a Combobox user's choice with any textbox.

I have assigned restrictions to the textboxes with a matching message box to pop up whenever the restriction is recognized, but when an appropriate value is typed into a textbox - I get a:

*runtime error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set*

While I don't have anything declared as an object or any "With" process throughout the entire code.
My code is:

**Note: Num_Molecules is the combobox name, Molecules_Hand is the textbox name.**

```
Private Sub Insert_Molecules_Click()

Dim lMolecules As Single

If Not Len(Trim(Num_Molecules.Value)) = 0 And Len(Trim(Molecules_Hand.Text)) = 0 Then
 lMolecules = Val(Num_Molecules.Value)

   ElseIf Len(Trim(Molecules_Hand.Text)) = 0 And Len(Trim(Num_Molecules.Value)) = 0 Then
      Molecules_Hand.Text = ""
        MsgBox "enter num of molecules"
         'Exit Sub

      ElseIf Molecules_Hand.Value < 5 And Len(Trim(Num_Molecules.Value)) = 0 Then
        Molecules_Hand.Text = ""
           MsgBox "value cannot be under 5"
            'Exit Sub

          ElseIf Molecules_Hand.Value >= 5 And Len(Trim(Num_Molecules.Value)) = 0 Then
           If Not Val(Molecules_Hand.Value) = Int(Val(Molecules_Hand.Value)) Then
             MsgBox "number must be an integer"
              'Exit Sub

               ElseIf IsNumeric(Molecules_Hand.Value) = False And Len(Trim(Num_Molecules.Value)) = 0 Then
                 MsgBox "textbox or choice cannot be empty"
                  'Exit Sub
            End If

Else
  lMolecules = Index_Form.Molecules_Hand.Value


End If
End Sub
```

The problem is with the last line before the "End If" - it just won't assign the textbox value to the variable. I have the same problem with all of my 3 textboxes and they are all assigned in the same way.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this on a user form named `Index_Form`? I notice that's the only line where you have a fully qualified name for the control.

Comment: @ Comintern: yes, it is the name of the user form, but actually whether if I refer to it specifically or not, it doesn't help and I get the same error.

Comment: This sub starts with `Private Sub Insert_Molecules_Click()`. What type of control is `Insert_Molecules`?

Comment: it's a command button, but what does it have to do with the error?

Comment: is there more code then this that runs while you click the cmdbutton?

Comment: Thanks all, I figured it out in the end. I had a problem with brackets misplaced and had to replace one of the "end if"s, now it's working.